# How does Hybris get the label of the attributes?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

label (java.lang.String): Key for the localized column name. The value is looked up in the localization bundles. If this string is blank, the column is named according to @qualifier.

For example type="AbstractOrder" in *-backoffice-config.xml:

```
<editorArea:tab name="hmc.properties"> 
...
  <editorArea:section name="hmc.common"> 
    <editorArea:attribute qualifier="name"/> 
    <editorArea:attribute qualifier="description"/> 
    <editorArea:attribute qualifier="expirationTime"/> 
  </editorArea:section> 
...
</editorArea:tab>
```

So, How do label attributes get from the database?
I don't undestand.
I tried reviewing two tables

> ATTRIBUTEDESCRIPTORS

and

> ATTRIBUTEDESCRIPTORSLP

But still not clear about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Labels are not taken from the Database. As you mentioned "***The value is looked up in the localization bundles***" which are not in DB. For example the label for the Product's **code** attribute can be found and modified for English language in ***core-locales_en.properties***:

```
type.product.code.name=Article Number
```

Comment: I dont think so. When i commented #type.abstractorder.expirationtime.name=Expiration Time Test or change value.then "ant clean all" and start server but label still not change

Comment: You also have to update your platform from hac -> Platform -> Update. (check only "Localize types")

Comment: How does it read this configuration file? Can you point out its flow code in Hybris core? How does the cache work for read values from this file? Thanks you.

Comment: As you noted above.
However, I still see the config value stored in the Database when you change the value. When I delete this value in the config file.Then ant clean all -> start server ->[ hac -> Platform -> Update. (check only "Localize types")]. Although the value in the config file was deleted but the label did not change (It is similar to the value in the database).So can say: Label value is configured in the config file. But if not found in the config file it will look in the Database. I think so.But I still do not understand the mechanism of its implementation...